# crontab not executing on centos7 container

Tags: docker, cron, centos7

As below, i have a centos7 container and i have a cron job configured. But it does not seem to be executing. What am i missing?

host: centos:7 docker container running on a mac

```
[root@a2118127510b /]# cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/ 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
[root@a2118127510b /]# 
[root@a2118127510b /]# date
Fri Sep 16 06:27:49 UTC 2016

[root@a2118127510b /]# crontab -l
no crontab for root

[root@a2118127510b /]# cat mycron      
* * * * * echo "hello" >> /var/log/cron1.log 2>&1

[root@a2118127510b /]# touch /var/log/cron1.log 

[root@a2118127510b /]# crontab -u root mycron 

[root@a2118127510b /]# crontab -l
* * * * * echo "hello" >> /var/log/cron1.log 2>&1

[root@a2118127510b /]# date
Fri Sep 16 06:27:55 UTC 2016
[root@a2118127510b /]# cat /var/log/cron1.log 

[root@a2118127510b /]# date
Fri Sep 16 06:32:03 UTC 2016
[root@a2118127510b /]# cat /var/log/cron1.log 
[root@a2118127510b /]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers (generally) only run one process, whereas in a typical VM/OS setup there are multiple services running in the background performing things like Cron execution and the like. It's likely that the Cron service isn't running in your container and therefore isn't triggering any Cron jobs.

You can check if the Cron service is running using `ps` or a similar command. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-start-restart-cron/ also gives information about starting and stopping the Cron service.

The most 'Dockerlike' approach would be to have a container that just ran the Cron process as it's single job running in foreground mode and displaying the output from the process instead of writing to a log file. https://github.com/aptible/docker-cron-example does something similar to this although it runs Cron in the background and then `tail` the log in the foreground.